# Apply shadows from another image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working on a floor design app that allows the user to pick preset floor images and view them within a preset room image.

I'm having problems with the last step, applying shadows from the original image.

I found an example of what I need to get.

1)[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX474.jpg) | [After replacing the texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzroJ.png) | [Applying shadows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHJmz.png)

So, how to apply shadows in this case?

UPD: more examples

2)[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aobuc.jpg) |
[After shadows transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cnqT.png)

3)[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWzOl.png) |
[After shadows transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INhtE.png)

In the first example, blending is actually used, since the line from the original floor was transferred to the final image. In other examples, most likely, not only blending was used, since the texture of the original floor is not transferred, only light and shadows.

How can I get too bright or too dark places on the original image and not highlight the texture of the floor?

Comment: What is wrong with what you did? Where is your code? Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Images are an example of what I should get, I need an algorithm for **how to apply shadows** to a new floor texture from the original image. How to get from image 2 - image 3.

Comment: There’s no algorithm for what you are requesting (at least not implemented in OpenCV), your problem is too specific. Maybe break down how you manually obtained the final image and try to automate each step using GENERAL PURPOSE image processing techniques.

Comment: What shadows do you want? I already see shadows on the appliances?  Do you mean floor shading? If so, do you mean brightness or coloration?

Comment: Your two images are not even at the same perspective or scale. So how do expect to transfer shadows. One would have to warp one image to match the other first. How did you make your third image?

Comment: If you can align and warp the floors to match geometry, then you could try taking the first images texture, converting to grayscale and using it to modulate the second image's floor texture. A hard light composite might do that.

Comment: I don't think they worked with shadows. I believe that they blended the texture with the original image, mirrored to simulate reflection.

Comment: I only have an example of how the algorithm works, I do not know the algorithm itself. I have implemented all the steps except the last one-applying shadows. In the first example, blending is actually used, since the line from the original floor was transferred to the final image. In other examples, most likely, not only blending was used, since the texture of the original floor is not transferred, only light and shadows.